# Adding class id to div of button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

So my button_to erb tag gives me something similar what is below and I was wondering if it was possible to add an id to the div by passing something along in the options hash rather than using js or adding html manually:

```html
<div>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="title">
<input name="auth_token">
</div>
```

My button erb code is just

```html
<%= button_to title, {}, :id => "button"%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really change the id of the parent div as far as I know.

The button_to options don't really allow for that [as you can see.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

You can add a class to the parent form though.  Not entirely certain why the div is added in with the button with the button_to command to be honest.

Comment: The link behind `as you can see` is still helpful and shows current `html_options` possibilities including `form:`

Answer (score 13):

As of 3.2, button_to accepts a hash of form attributes via the html_options key "form"

```
<%= button_to title, {}, :form => { :id => "button" } %>
```

Comment: As of Rails 5.2 there is also a separate `form_class` parameter in html_options in case you set e.g. CSS by class instead by id `<%= button_to title, {}, form_class: 'very_immportant_form' %>`